# Sending request to API server return nothing

Tags: php, api

actually I'm working on coding an API for my business, I have an issue on my code and I couldn't figure out the problem, here is the class:

```
<?php
class ApiCaller
{
    //some variables for the object
    private $_app_id;
    private $_app_key;
    private $_api_url;

    //construct an ApiCaller object, taking an
    //APP ID, APP KEY and API URL parameter
    public function __construct($app_id, $app_key, $api_url)
    {
        $this->_app_id = $app_id;
        $this->_app_key = $app_key;
        $this->_api_url = $api_url;
    }

    //send the request to the API server
    //also encrypts the request, then checks
    //if the results are valid
    public function sendRequest($request_params)
    {
        //encrypt the request parameters
        $enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->_app_key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

        //create the params array, which will
        //be the POST parameters
        $params = array();
        $params['enc_request'] = $enc_request;
        $params['app_id'] = $this->_app_id;

        //initialize and setup the curl handler
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        //execute the request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //json_decode the result
        $result = @json_decode($result);        

        //check if we're able to json_decode the result correctly
        if( $result == false || isset($result->success) == false ) {
            throw new Exception('Request was not correct');         
        }

        //if there was an error in the request, throw an exception
        if( $result->success == false ) {
            throw new Exception($result->errormsg);
        }

        //if everything went great, return the data
        return $result->data;
    }
}
```

The problem that there is no data returned from the sendRequest function, just throw 'Request was not correct' exception, I tried to test the code but with no luck. I'm using xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11 and I have curl-7.43.0-win64 installed,,,

Any help will be appreciated and thanks.

Edit:
I use this code to test the function and it worked:

```
<?php
$_app_key = '28e336ac6c9423d946ba02d19c6a2632';
$_api_url = 'http://localhost/myAPI/simpletodo_api/';
$_app_id = 'APP001';
$params = array(
    'controller' => 'todo',
    'action' => 'read',
    'username' => 'nikko',
    'userpass' =>'test1234'
);
$enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $_app_key, json_encode($params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
$pa = array();
$pa['enc_request'] = $enc_request;
$pa['app_id'] = $_app_id;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pa);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$errorNo = curl_errno ($ch );
$result = @json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
```

and the result:
"object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["todo_id"]=> string(10) "1323343689" ["title"]=> string(10) "test title" ["description"]=> string(28) "test description weee wasted" ["due_date"]=> string(10) "12/02/2011" ["is_done"]=> string(4) "true" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) { ["todo_id"]=> string(10) "1323429521" ["title"]=> string(3) "wee" ["description"]=> string(11) "adsa wasada" ["due_date"]=> string(10) "12/21/2011" ["is_done"]=> string(4) "true" } } ["success"]=> bool(true) }"

So where is the problem then??

Comment: are you sure you are sending the request to the right place, and that it is actually returning data that you think it is. if you get a 404 not found how do you know in the above code?  Where is this at?  $error = curl_errno ($ch ); http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php

Comment: Please refer to the question again, I updated it, thank you very much

Comment: you updated it, but why are you testing a apple to see if an orange is orange.  Testing code like the other code is fine, but it doesn't tell us what $result is inside of the class method, by testing bits of it outside of the class.  Maybe your input to the class method is completely messed up, maybe your key for encryption is wrong, there is no way to know what values the class has, which is probably the issue.  What are the values when you construct the class? what are $request_params when you call the sendRequest method, there is no way to know these.

Comment: Thanks dude, I already figured out the problem and fix it

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull with the following line :

`$result = @json_decode($result);`

You are hiding any error message by using the `@`.

I would suspect you are not receiving a valid json response and then $result would be set to false, because json_decode would not work.

So what happens if you not getting a valid json back? Your code should handle that error case.

In order to debug, try to add `var_dump($result);` just after the `curl_exec` call, that should help you understand what's wrong.

Comment: Please refer to the question again, I updated it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments you should check the curl error codes

```
$errorNo = curl_errno ($ch );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php

In the case of a 404 or other error you have no way to know in your code as formatted.

Comment: Please refer to the question again, I updated it, thank you very much